# Prove that p is valid if and only if $\emptyset \vDash p$.

Tags: proof-writing, first-order-logic

I am trying to solve the problem my textbook suggests:
[image]

Here is how I proved that one and I'd like to know if my proof makes sense and can be accepted.

Let's prove it by contradiction. As such, let some statement $p$ be valid, i.e. true under all possible interpretations, and assume $\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset, \mathcal{S} \vDash p$.

To prove that I need the following lemma:
$$\mathcal{S} \cup \{s\} \vDash p \land \mathcal{S} \cup \{ \lnot s \} \vDash p \implies \mathcal{S} \vDash p$$
...which means that if some statement $s$ and it's negation both prove some statement $p$, than $s$ can be dropped, it does not actually required to prove $p$.

Now, since $\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset$, there exists some statement $s \in \mathcal{S}$ and it can be one of the three:

1. Another valid statement, i.e. "always true".
2. A contradiction, i.e. "always false".
3. Neither of above.

**Case 1.**
If $s$ is valid, then only the empty set of interpretations can satisfy the $\mathcal{S} \cup \{ \lnot s \} \vDash p$ subformula from the lemma above, since by definition any valid statement must be true under any possible interpretation, thus $\lnot s$ is impossible. As such, by the lemma above, $s$ is redundant in the $\mathcal{S}$.

**Case 2.**
If $s$ is a negation of some valid formula, i.e. it is always false, then the same reasoning as in the "case 1" applies with minor change that $\mathcal{S} \cup \{ s \} \vDash p$ can be satisfied by only the empty set of interpretations. Once again, $s$ can be dropped.

**Case 3.**
If $s$ can be true under some interpretations and false under others, then the lemma above still applies since no matter whether $s$ or $\lnot s$ holds, $p$ remains true by the definition of validity. As such, once again, $s$ is redundant.

Thus, by repeating the procedure described above it must be the case that only $\emptyset$ contains no superfluous statement $s$, so $\mathcal{S} = \emptyset$.

Comment: You "assume $\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset, \mathcal{S} \vDash p$".  What is your justification for this assumption?

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me. I *think* you're trying to show that the minimal set $S$ with $S\models p$ is $\emptyset$; this is true, but it's largely irrelevant.

Comment: Moreover, even if you justified that assumption, it is not clear how you would get to $\emptyset\models p$ by iterating your argument.  What if the $\mathcal{S}$ you started with was infinite?

Comment: @EricWofsey well, since I need a contradiction, I start with nonempty set and try to show that it can not be; thus set must be empty. Regarding infinite iteration.. I have no answer. I am not a mathematician and just learning how to prove theorems, so I expected my proof to be wrong. But what stops me from applying my procedure infinite number of times to some infinite set?

Comment: $\mathcal{S} \neq \emptyset, \mathcal{S} \vDash p$ is **not** the negation of $\emptyset\models p$!  That would be like saying the negation of "I am the president of the United States" is "I am the president of some country different from the United States".

Comment: If it is *valid* it is consequence of **every** set of sentences (apply the def of logical cons): thus, also the empty one.

Comment: For the converse, consider what means to be cons of the empty set: there is no valuation that satisfies the empty set and not satisfy D.